# What's the meaning of "mellow mama"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, american-english

What's the meaning of "mellow mama" in this description?
I found this expression in a recipe book, but I don't understand what it means:

> Pulling from the inspiration of a green goddess dressing, this blend will channel your inner **mellow mama**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mellow is an adjective: *Mellow defines someone or something that is calm, smooth and free from harshness.*

> A person who is calm and peaceful and doesn't get upset easily is an example of a person who is mellow.

[Source](https://www.yourdictionary.com/mellow)

And mama refers to "mom" which is either a mother or a lady that for instance is friendly and helpful toward a lot of people.

So in conclusion "mellow mama" refer to a lady who is calm and peaceful and doesn't get upset easily. Someone you can trust.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but why "mama"?

Answer (score 1):

“Mama” is used slangily here to refer to a woman (not necessarily a mother). I think it’s a usage that’s common in “wellness” circles - someone writing an “anti-anxiety diet” book would quite likely be in that milieu and I’m not surprised they would speak this way. “Mellow mama” is alliterative and kind of a parallel to “green goddess”, used earlier in the sentence, which is also alliterative (this means that every word begins with the same sound). Basically, this is a cute way of saying that the recipe will make you feel calm and relaxed.

Comment: Actually I see it as a reference to a hippie woman, especially in context with “goddess”. According to Wikipedia “In the early 1970s, salad dressing maker Seven Seas produced a bottled version of this dressing.” Both “mama” and “mellow” were popular slang term in the late 60s in America.

Comment: @ColleenV that makes sense, and I think there is definitely overlap between 60s hippie culture and modern “wellness” culture or whatever you might call this. Both make me think of the West Coast of the U.S. and I think both would have had an interest in healthy living, inner peace, etc.